# how to create jar of a groovy project in intellij indea

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, jar

I have create a jar of my groovy project using artifact in intellij idea adding groovy lib in project settings. But when I run that jar following exception occurs

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovyObject
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

May be the problem is creating jar. How can I create jar of a groovy project in intellij Idea.

Comment: You need to run the jar with `classpath` configured.

Comment: Is it always need to run jar with classpath configured. I want to run just double clicking the jar.

Comment: So you need to prepare so called fat jar.

Comment: How can i do it ?? It does not matter how fat it is :D

Comment: It can be done with appropriate plugin. [Here](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) is one for gradle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the gradle support in Intellij Idea.

1. **First active gradle support for your project in Intellij Idea** as described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/working-with-gradle-projects.html
2. **Move your source to the default gradle directory tree**. The groovy source files must be moved in `src/main/groovy/...` and the test sources in `src/test/groovy/...`. (PS: You can configure gradle to look for sources in other directories than the default ones, but is easier and safer to move the sources).

   [image]

   In the screenshot you see a directory tree for java sources. You use `groovy` instead.
3. **Than add a gradle build file in the root directory of your project**.

   A basic gradle file (which must be named build.gradle) can look like so:

   ```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {}
    }

    apply plugin: 'groovy'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    jar {
        baseName = 'your_project_name'
        version =  '0.1.0'
        manifest {
            attributes("Build-Time": new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                    "Build-Jdk": System.getProperty("java.version"),
                    "Built-By": System.getProperty("user.name"),
                    "Created-By": "Gradle",
            )
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    // java version dependency
    sourceCompatibility = 1.7
    targetCompatibility = 1.7

    dependencies {
        // your local jar dependency
        compile files('./lib/your_jar.jar')
        // groovy
        compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.1.9'

        //other useful dependencies
        compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
        testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.3'
    }
   ```
4. **Now use the gradle plugin in Intellij**:
   [image]
5. Wenn Intellij finish building, you can find your executable jar in `build/libs/your_project_name.jar`